# increase the page limit

Tags: page-numbering, page

The question looks weird, however, I am dealing with a template that has several packages and multiple .cls files. This template has a page limit of 12, and I am unable to find the corresponding line to change it in the .cls file(s). Is there any way to increase this 12 page limit?

I tried using `\setcounter{page}{x}`, however I failed.

link for the template that I am using: http://tst.tsinghuajournals.com/EN/column/column2218.shtml

Comment: Are the template files available online somewhere for download by members of the general public?

Comment: (1) if you have been given a template that explicitly forces you to have no more than 12 pages, then you write no more than 12 pages (otherwise you're just going to annoy the person setting the limit). (2) if it is a consequence of something you did, then we need to see code. We are not magicians.

Comment: @Mico added the link.

Comment: @daleif, Basically, while submission, they did not mention the page limit, however, I find that after page 12, the page counter resets to zero.

Comment: I couldn't replicate your issue. I downloaded the template, added a bunch of `\lipsum` paragraphs and the page number went up to 13.